Kendo Grid UI getting sum to remain in same place on screen
I am wanting to create a table that calls an API and generate values. IT will then calculate a sum that will be at the bottom of the table. The grid has a horizontal scroll and I am wanting it to when you scroll, no matter what the sum will remain on the right side of its row. As of now it is all working except I can only use center text or right align text for it to display. I am wanting it to be able to always be on the right no matter when you scroll it.
I have not been able to find documentation that points me in the right direction. I have looked into the kendo documents and much else. I am sure that I am just looking over it or something.

look into sticky columns - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/sticky/
